# How can I change locale/encoding to avoid getting weird characters in terminal?

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, locale, putty

I have installed `tree` on my ubuntu box, when i connect to it from Putty and  I launch `tree` i get this :

```
$ tree
âââ html.vim -> xml.vim
âââ js.vim -> xml.vim
âââ xml.vim
```

instead of this :

```
$ tree --charset=ANSII
|-- html.vim -> xml.vim
|-- js.vim -> xml.vim
`-- xml.vim
```

I also get this problem when e.g. I list my packages from `npm` (package manager from `nodejs`)

```
$ npm list
/home/monkey/scripts/chatter
âââŹ express@3.0.6
â âââ buffer-crc32@0.1.1
â âââ commander@0.6.1
â âââŹ connect@2.7.2
â â âââ bytes@0.1.0
```

How can I change that (either from Putty or linux box) ?

Comment: Change the character translation in PuTTY to UTF-8.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the character translation in PuTTY to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Putty Menu > `Change Settings...` > `Category :` `Window` > `Translation` > `Remote Character Set` = **UTF-8**